# filter array and get max values ​of nested array of each set of objects in javascrip

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, max

I would like to filter from the nested array whose condition is count_buyer greater than 0 and then get the max purchase_amount from buyers all this while maintaining the nested array hierarchy.

I have data in an array like this

```
var data = [
      {
        'product':'laptop',
        'count_buyer':3,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Vins', 'purchase_amount': 27 },
              { 'name': 'Jan', 'purchase_amount': 38 },
              { 'name': 'Alex', 'purchase_amount': 80 },
        ]
      },
      {
        'product':'televisor',
        'count_buyer':2,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Carl', 'purchase_amount': 25 },
              { 'name': 'Digi', 'purchase_amount': 40 }
        ]
      },
      {
        'product':'ropa varon',
        'count_buyer':0,
        'buyers':[]
      }
    ];
```

first I want to filter the objects that they have in their buyers array.

```
[     
      {
        'product':'laptop',
        'count_buyer':3,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Vins', 'purchase_amount': 27 },
              { 'name': 'Jan', 'purchase_amount': 38 },
              { 'name': 'Alex', 'purchase_amount': 80 },
        ]
      },
      {
        'product':'televisor',
        'count_buyer':2,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Carl', 'purchase_amount': 25 },
              { 'name': 'Digi', 'purchase_amount': 40 }
        ]
      },
]
```

then filter the maximum number of buyers whose condition is the maximum purchase_amount

```
[     
      {
        'product':'laptop',
        'count_buyer':3,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Alex', 'purchase_amount': 80 },
        ]
      },
      {
        'product':'televisor',
        'count_buyer':2,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Digi', 'purchase_amount': 40 }
        ]
      },
]
```

this is my code

```js
var data = [
  {
    'product':'laptop',
    'count_buyer':3,
    'buyers':[
          { 'name': 'Vins', 'purchase_amount': 27 },
          { 'name': 'Jan', 'purchase_amount': 38 },
          { 'name': 'Alex', 'purchase_amount': 80 },
    ]
  },
  {
    'product':'televisor',
    'count_buyer':2,
    'buyers':[
          { 'name': 'Carl', 'purchase_amount': 25 },
          { 'name': 'Digi', 'purchase_amount': 40 }
    ]
  },
  {
    'product':'ropa varon',
    'count_buyer':0,
    'buyers':[]
  }
];
var filter0 = data.filter(count=> count.count_buyer > 0 )
var max = filter0.filter(buye => buye.buyers.reduce(function (prev, current) {
   return (prev.purchase_amount > current.purchase_amount) ? prev : current
}));
console.log(max)
```

but the result is like this

```
[     
      {
        'product':'laptop',
        'count_buyer':3,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Vins', 'purchase_amount': 27 },
              { 'name': 'Jan', 'purchase_amount': 38 },
              { 'name': 'Alex', 'purchase_amount': 80 },
        ]
      },
      {
        'product':'televisor',
        'count_buyer':2,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Carl', 'purchase_amount': 25 },
              { 'name': 'Digi', 'purchase_amount': 40 }
        ]
      },
]
```

How could I get to this result?

```
[     
      {
        'product':'laptop',
        'count_buyer':3,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Alex', 'purchase_amount': 80 },
        ]
      },
      {
        'product':'televisor',
        'count_buyer':2,
        'buyers':[
              { 'name': 'Digi', 'purchase_amount': 40 }
        ]
      },
]
```

Comment: there is a way to do this in one pass using map and filter

Answer (score 2):

After the `.reduce`, once you find the buyer with the maximum `purchase_amount`, create a new `buyers` array with that result as its one item.

Using `.map` and object spread/rest to avoid mutating the existing data, you can use:

```js
var data = [
  {
    'product':'laptop',
    'count_buyer':3,
    'buyers':[
          { 'name': 'Vins', 'purchase_amount': 27 },
          { 'name': 'Jan', 'purchase_amount': 38 },
          { 'name': 'Alex', 'purchase_amount': 80 },
    ]
  },
  {
    'product':'televisor',
    'count_buyer':2,
    'buyers':[
          { 'name': 'Carl', 'purchase_amount': 25 },
          { 'name': 'Digi', 'purchase_amount': 40 }
    ]
  },
  {
    'product':'ropa varon',
    'count_buyer':0,
    'buyers':[]
  }
];

const output = data
  .filter(({ buyers }) => buyers.length)
  .map(({ buyers, ...rest }) => {
    const maxBuyer = buyers.reduce((a, b) => a.purchase_amount > b.purchase_amount ? a : b);
    return { ...rest, buyers: [maxBuyer] };
  });
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the library [rubico](https://github.rubico.land) to simplify the method we're about to use to do this in one pass: **transducers**. If you don't know what they are, I wrote a crash course [here](https://github.rubico.land#transducers). First I will show you how to do it with two passes, i.e.

`[...products] => [...products_with_buyers]`

`[...products_with_buyers] => [...products_with_max_buyer]`.

```js
const { transform, pipe, assign, map, filter, reduce, get, gt } = require('rubico')

const getMaxBuyer = (y, xi) => y.purchase_amount > xi.purchase_amount ? y : xi

const getProductsWithMaxBuyer = pipe([
  filter(gt(get('buyers.length'), 0)), // [...products] => [...products_with_buyers]
  map(assign({
    buyers: pipe([
      get('buyers'), // product => product.buyers
      reduce(getMaxBuyer), // buyers => [max_buyer]
    ]), // assign [max_buyer] the result to the 'buyers' property on the product
  })) // [...products_with_buyers] => [...products_with_max_buyer]
])

getProductsWithMaxBuyer(data) /* creates an intermediate array `product_with_buyers`
[
  {
    product: 'laptop',
    count_buyer: 3,
    buyers: { name: 'Alex', purchase_amount: 80 }
  },
  {
    product: 'televisor',
    count_buyer: 2,
    buyers: { name: 'Digi', purchase_amount: 40 }
  }
]
*/
```

This is how you do it in one pass.

`[...products] => [...products_with_max_buyer]`

```js
transform(
  getProductsWithMaxBuyer,
  [],
)(data) /* => [ does not create any intermediate arrays, everything is one pass
  {
    product: 'laptop',
    count_buyer: 3,
    buyers: { name: 'Alex', purchase_amount: 80 }
  },
  {
    product: 'televisor',
    count_buyer: 2,
    buyers: { name: 'Digi', purchase_amount: 40 }
  }
] */
```

The difference here is the context in which rubico's functions are used. They are "smart" enough to know if they should behave as transducers. If you'd like to read more, check out the [intro](https://github.rubico.land#introduction) and the [docs](https://github.rubico.land#documentation)